# Does anyone know John Powell's composition technique(s)?

Tags: film

John Powell is one of my favorite, if not my my absolute favorite, composers. He creates and manages his themes so well and his harmonies are... the best. I am the kind of person who sees something they like and instantly wants to know every detail (often un-google-able) about that subject. I wanna know!!! you know? I don't know...

What is his routine, I guess you would say, for coming up with themes?

How does he rationalise switches from theme to theme (or does he just do it)?

Does he only compose themes for a project, or does he keep, maybe, like a stash of backup theme samples or something?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of good interviews with him online. From those I've gleaned the following things he's been inspired by:

1. Instrument technology (synthesizers and so forth). Also, unusual instruments or vocal sounds.
2. Classic movies (*The Great Escape*) and film composers (Zimmer, Williams).
3. Creating something different, that doesn't sound like everyone else.
4. The mood or content of a specific scene.
5. The structural demands of the temporary music used by the filmmakers (he does NOT like to have to follow this).
6. Music improvised by his own child.
7. Music from his own previous movies (if doing a sequel).

It sounds like he typically creates music new, from scratch, in response to specific scenes in the movies he's working on, except when he's taking direct inspiration from earlier movie scores (his own, or other people's).

SOURCES:

http://legacy.aintitcool.com/node/31099
https://www.starwars.com/news/solo-a-star-wars-story-composer-john-powell
https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/john-powell-interview-scoring-bourne-hans-zimmer-faceoff-and-more/
https://collider.com/how-to-train-your-dragon-2-john-powell-interview/